# jquery obj.find problem in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this snippet of code, which fails at var link:

```
var obj = $(this[0]);     
var html = obj.html();
var link = html.find('a[href*=/comment/reply]');
```

This is an ajax response from a submitted form.  The output of what I get back from the var html is as follows:

```
===><div class="comment-new-success"><a id="new"></a>
<a id="comment-482"></a>
<div class="comment">
<div class="submitted">Submitted by <a href="/user/1" title="View user profile.">NAME</a> on Sun, 07/10/2011 - 12:48.<span class="new"> *new</span></div>
<div class="content clearfix"><p>123123123123122</p>
</div>
<div class="links_box"><ul class="links"><li class="comment_delete first"><a href="/comment/delete/482?token=e1fba5ef1c99c5a3760313b53f582972">delete</a></li>
<li class="comment_edit"><a href="/comment/edit/482">edit</a></li>
<li class="comment_reply last"><a href="/comment/reply/6/482">reply</a></li>
</ul></div></div>
</div><===(string)
```

How do I properly get the "/comment/reply/6/482" variable as the var link in the above example.  The code (I thought) should work fine, but doesn't

Comment: actually, this was the right query I found:    var link = $(this[0]).find('.comment_reply a').attr('href');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was this:

```
var link = $(this[0]).find('.comment_reply a').attr('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[href*="/comment/reply"]')
```

See my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hCbt3/ I grabbed the text from the link just to demonstrate it's correctly selecting the anchor.

Or grab the more specific one if you have more than one comment/reply:

```
$('a[href*="/comment/reply/6/482"]')
```

Comment: the problem is that this HTML code is not on the page, the html code is a response from ajax.  it is in the var obj.  How would I get it from the var obj?  obj.find.$('a[href*="/comment/reply/6/482"]') -- obj.find('a[href*="/comment/reply/6/482"]'); those fail.

Comment: You're searching for the element before you insert the html into the document then?

Comment: found the answer.  The answer was this:

    var link = $(this[0]).find('.comment_reply a').attr('href');

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('a[href^="/comment/reply/"]')
```

Per JQuery docs, the [Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) has the syntax: `[name^="value"]` and will select elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string.

Comment: the problem is that this HTML code is not on the page, the html code is a response from ajax. it is in the var obj. That is where I need to limit the search to.